# UV mapping issues while loading collada model exported with Sketchup

Tags: collada, three.js

I load collada models, exported via Google Sketchup, into my Three.js (v63) scene with the Three.js collada loader.

The models are loaded, but with some, textures aren't well mapped, like in the following picture :
[image]

My first question is how to detect this kind of problems and then, is there a way to leverage the exported UVs from sketchup to correctly map the textures ?

The model from the sceenshot comes from : http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=557d5f1b5a076bdcf53b1b21212345ca&prevstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Are those textures projected? If so make unique, triangulate n-gons and then export.

3D Warehouse models typically acquire their textures from 2 sources. Google Street View and Google Earth. The textures are typical projected at the geometry so the UV coords are skewed because it is a viewed based mapping.

When you mix projection with n-gons and then export you'll typically end up with the mesh getting triangulated. This triangulation messes up the projection.

SketchUp uses unconventional mapping methods so careful texturing is needed. Triangulating in Sketchup prior to exporting is always advised.

Hopefully that will add more info to why your export looks the way is does.

There are tools available to fix such issues.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained how and why this would help the OP, and what to do if the textures are not projected.

Comment: amended answer. hope it clarifies it bit more for the OP